request for peer reviewed articles using Markov Chains tools
I am a mathematician setting up an REU for next semester. Students have background in modeling with ODES (population growth models, predator-prey relations, neuron firing models; stability analysis of linear and nonlinear systems, stable limit cycles). They have expressed interest in learning about Markov Chains, so I'm currently preparing some material on probability and textbook applications of Markov Chains techniques in the life sciences. I'm having more trouble identifying recent-ish peer reviewed important publications where Markov Chain techniques are used in a substantial way for important questions in biology or medicine. Any field of bio/med works, I just want to come up with a few recent (i.e. last decade), impactful examples of how these techniques are relevant.

Markov chains are so fundamental to many approaches that they are unlikely to be explicitly called out. MCMC is very commonly used (e.g. phylogenetics), Just about any model of biological sequences uses a Markov chain somewhere (e.g. Hidden Markov Models). The issue may be that the tools are older/more fundamental and less explicitly about MCs than you want.

This question is better for https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com - you will certainly not get downvotes there and likely get a reasonable answer

Not recent, but here are several references for MrBayes, a classic phylogenetics program using (MC)MCMC. The links page there also has some tools for visualizing MCMC chains. Structure is another neat program taking advantage of MCMC. (FWIW, I wouldn't have necessarily called these applications bioinformatics, but maybe today they would be.)

I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question about a specific problem in biology, the remit of this site, as laid out in the [Tour].

Basically if you post the question on bioinformatics SE I'll answer it for you. Your call.
